# Emulating MTU problems - how can I drop large packets

Tags: linux, router, iptables, mtu

When I'm out and about with my laptop I use OpenVPN to connect across public WiFi back to my server. Occasionally I come across what I have to assume are MTU issues - large packets get dropped, smaller packets get through.

Given that in this situations I have no control over the public WiFi service, and the local provider has almost certainly just installed a "black box" and knows nothing about the technical issues, I can't fix the underlying issue and instead I have to find a suitable workaround. Inevitably, being away from one's normal environment is never a convenient time to try and fix such problems, so I end up having to "make do".

I would like to configure a test environment that allows me to emulate MTU problems so that I can find a suitable solution for use when I'm out and about.

I use a Windows client, but for OpenVPN I don't think that's of great import. I have some direct control of the Linux-based server (it's actually a [Sophos UTM](https://www.sophos.com/en/products/free-tools/sophos-utm-home-edition.aspx)). Within the lab environment I can insert one or more Linux-based devices in a chain between my client and the server.

Any suggestions for intentionally dropping large UDP packets (e.g 1200 < size <= 1500), please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ensure Don't Fragment bit is on :

```
echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_no_pmtu_disc
```

Then, you can change your interface MTU :

```
ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1200
```

If an UDP packet > 1200 comes, it will be dropped.

By the way, [this link](https://www.zeitgeist.se/2013/11/26/mtu-woes-in-ipsec-tunnels-how-to-fix/) could help you to solve your VPN MTU related issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not looking for an answer to the "Why do my large packets get dropped", though. What I need is some way of repeating the broken environment when I've got time to address it. I'll take a look at the `ip_no_pmtu_disc` flag - appreciated.

Comment: Setting the MTU to 1200 and disable the fragmentation should do the trick so.